# Matlab Matrix Minimization

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix

```
R=(A-C)*inv(A+B-C-C')*(A-C');
```

where `A` and `B` are n by n matrices. I want to find n*n matrix `C` such that the determinant of `R` is minimized, SO:

```
C=arg min (det(R));
```

Is there any function in MATLAB that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to find the minimum of an unconstrained multivariable function. This can probably be achieved with [fminunc](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html)

```
fun = @(x)x(1)*exp(-(x(1)^2 + x(2)^2)) + (x(1)^2 + x(2)^2)/20;
x0 = [1,2];
[x,fval] = fminunc(fun,x0)
```

Note that there are no examples in the documentation where a matrix is used, this is probably because horrendous performance could be expected when trying to solve this problem for a matrix of any nontiny size. (This is not because of matlab, but because of the nature of the problem).

It is also good to realize that this method does not (cannot) guarantee an optimum, only a local optimum.